About structural integrity of a metal table
I'm making a simple table-like design for a contact angle machine. It needs to have levelers so the samples are symmetric. For simplicty's sake, cost efficiency and weight I decided to use a steel base of around 7 mm thick, 320mm large and 250mm wide in which four prefabricated levelers are attached by threading (see picture). My worries are that the design might lack some structural integrity and not rigid enough. I think it accomplishes stability (not likely to tilt and fall and the weight is enough to create enough friction and avoid pushing the equipment by accident), and the material is resistant enough to hold the weight of the components of the equipment.
Is there a way to prove that this concept is OK from engineering stand point? any standards about this kind of metal structures? what kind of distance should I use between legs? minimum distance between holes and edges?
[

sounds solid. It is useful to include information about the loads, impact forces, and worst-case scenarios.
